# Get all subpaths in a hierarchical query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I've a table that contains a list of sales departments as follows:

```
+-------+---------------+-----------+
|DEPT_ID|DEPT_NAME      |DEPT_PARENT|
+-------+---------------+-----------+
|5500   |World          |           |
|5510   |Region 1       |5500       |
|5511   |Cell 1 Region 1|5510       |
|5512   |Cell 2 Region 1|5510       |
|5513   |Cell 3 Region 1|5510       |
|5514   |Cell 4 Region 1|5510       |
|5515   |Cell 5 Region 1|5510       |
|5520   |Region 2       |5500       |
|5521   |Cell 1 Region 2|5520       |
|5522   |Cell 2 Region 2|5520       |
|5530   |Region 3       |5500       |
|5531   |Cell 1 Region 3|5530       |
|5532   |Cell 2 Region 3|5530       |
|5540   |Region 4       |5500       |
|5533   |Cell 1 Region 4|5540       |
|5534   |Cell 2 Region 4|5533       |
|5590   |Region 5       |5500       |
|5591   |Cell 1 Region 5|5590       |
+-------+---------------+-----------+
```

I need a query that returns all possible subpaths. So for the first three rows it should be as follows:

```
5500 5510
5500 5511
5510 5511
```

so for each possible subpath it would return the first and last department of the path. It is fairly easy to get the path by doing this:

```
    SELECT d.*, LTRIM (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (dept_id, '-'), '-') AS PATH
      FROM depts d
START WITH dept_parent IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR dept_id = dept_parent
```

but how I can get all possible subpaths?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` to find the start of the path.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE depts ( DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME, DEPT_PARENT ) AS
SELECT 5500, 'World',           NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5510, 'Region 1',        5500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5511, 'Cell 1 Region 1', 5510 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5512, 'Cell 2 Region 1', 5510 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5513, 'Cell 3 Region 1', 5510 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5514, 'Cell 4 Region 1', 5510 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5515, 'Cell 5 Region 1', 5510 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5520, 'Region 2',        5500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5521, 'Cell 1 Region 2', 5520 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5522, 'Cell 2 Region 2', 5520 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5530, 'Region 3',        5500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5531, 'Cell 1 Region 3', 5530 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5532, 'Cell 2 Region 3', 5530 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5540, 'Region 4',        5500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5533, 'Cell 1 Region 4', 5540 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5534, 'Cell 2 Region 4', 5533 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5590, 'Region 5',        5500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5591, 'Cell 1 Region 5', 5590 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( dept_parent ) AS ancestor,
       dept_id,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( dept_parent, '>' ) || '>' || dept_id AS path
FROM   depts
START WITH dept_parent IS NOT NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR dept_id = dept_parent;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ANCESTOR | DEPT_ID | PATH                
> -------: | ------: | :-------------------
>     5500 |    5510 | >5500>5510          
>     5500 |    5511 | >5500>5510>5511     
>     5500 |    5512 | >5500>5510>5512     
>     5500 |    5513 | >5500>5510>5513     
>     5500 |    5514 | >5500>5510>5514     
>     5500 |    5515 | >5500>5510>5515     
>     5500 |    5520 | >5500>5520          
>     5500 |    5521 | >5500>5520>5521     
>     5500 |    5522 | >5500>5520>5522     
>     5500 |    5530 | >5500>5530          
>     5500 |    5531 | >5500>5530>5531     
>     5500 |    5532 | >5500>5530>5532     
>     5500 |    5540 | >5500>5540          
>     5500 |    5533 | >5500>5540>5533     
>     5500 |    5534 | >5500>5540>5533>5534
>     5500 |    5590 | >5500>5590          
>     5500 |    5591 | >5500>5590>5591     
>     5510 |    5511 | >5510>5511          
>     5510 |    5512 | >5510>5512          
>     5510 |    5513 | >5510>5513          
>     5510 |    5514 | >5510>5514          
>     5510 |    5515 | >5510>5515          
>     5520 |    5521 | >5520>5521          
>     5520 |    5522 | >5520>5522          
>     5530 |    5531 | >5530>5531          
>     5530 |    5532 | >5530>5532          
>     5533 |    5534 | >5533>5534          
>     5540 |    5533 | >5540>5533          
>     5540 |    5534 | >5540>5533>5534     
>     5590 |    5591 | >5590>5591
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5117cd842f4310db953d1a7c4c63f8e)*

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to generate a closure table, that contains all possible paths in the hierarchy.

Here is a solution that uses a standard recursive query to achieve that. I also added a column that stores the depth of the relationship, since this information is often useful in closure tables.

```
with cte(node_id, dept_id, dept_parent, lvl) as (
    select dept_id node_id, dept_id, dept_parent, 0 lvl from dept
    union all 
    select c.node_id, d.dept_id, d.dept_parent, c.lvl + 1
    from cte c
    inner join dept d on d.dept_id = c.dept_parent
)
select dept_id ancestor, node_id node, lvl 
from cte 
where lvl > 0
order by node, ancestor
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eceb22d0424b8b61552b22ed0453d4db)** with your sample data produces 30 rows, whose first 10 are:

```
ANCESTOR | NODE | LVL
-------: | ---: | --:
    5500 | 5510 |   1
    5500 | 5511 |   2
    5510 | 5511 |   1
    5500 | 5512 |   2
    5510 | 5512 |   1
    5500 | 5513 |   2
    5510 | 5513 |   1
    5500 | 5514 |   2
    5510 | 5514 |   1
    5500 | 5515 |   2
```